# how to Send and Receive files without closing socket

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, server, client

Trying to make a client who sends and receives files(images,text files)
The question is there a way to send file and not close the socket to make it receive files later.
i found that i can open two threads for receiving and sending but i could not no how.
is there any way to make this possible by adding a new socket.

my client code:

```
filename='48469.jpg'
TCP_IP = 'localhost'
TCP_PORT = 9001
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

s = socket.socket()
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
f = open(filename,'rb')
while True:
    l = f.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
    while (l):
        s.sendall(l)
        #print('Sent ',repr(l))
        l = f.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if not l:
        print ('file close()')
        s.close()
        #where I did closed the socket because
        #otherwise the server wont stop from receiving data
        f.close()
        break
print("1")


f = open('received_from_server.txt', 'wb')
print ('file opened')
while True:
    #print('receiving data...')
    data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if not data:
        f.close()
        print ('file close()')
        break
    # write data to a file
    f.write(data)
print("2")
print('Successfully get the file')
s.close()
print('connection closed')
```

my server code:

```
filename='112.txt'
TCP_IP = 'localhost'
TCP_PORT = 9001
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

class ClientThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self,ip,port,sock):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.sock = sock
        print ("New thread started for "+ip+":"+str(port))

    def run(self):
        f = open(filename,'rb')
        while True:
            l = f.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
            while (l):
                self.sock.send(l)
                #print('Sent ',repr(l))
                l = f.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
            if not l:
                f.close()
                self.sock.close()
                break

tcpsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
tcpsock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
tcpsock.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
threads = []

while True:
    tcpsock.listen(5)
    print ("Waiting for incoming connections...")
    (conn, (ip,port)) = tcpsock.accept()
    print ('Got connection from ', (ip,port))
    f = open('received_from_client.jpg', 'wb')
    print ('file opened')
    while True:
        data =  conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        if not data:
            print("8")
            f.close()
            print ('file close()')
            break
        # write data to a file
        f.write(data)
    print("1")
    newthread = ClientThread(ip,port,conn)
    print("2")
    newthread.start()
    threads.append(newthread)

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

currently its showing me an error

> a operation was attempted on something that is not a socket"

Comment: You don't need another socket, you need an appropriate protocol, e.g. one with a header containing a 'content-length' field that allows end-of-message to be determined without closing the socket...

Comment: You need some kind of file transfer protocol to transfer a file. Have a loot at HTTP, FTP, TFTP, or any other such protocol to learn how such protocols are designed and implemented.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53145147/235698) to a similar question is an example.