# How to send integer through socket in python

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, server, integer, client-server

Actually, I want to send integers through the server to client and vice versa. So that I can apply some operations on them on the client/server side. But whenever I a try to send integers, the server or client gets automatically destroyed even without sending the message. I have also used a while loop but it's not working as it was supposed to do?

Also, it works fine when I send strings (encoded)

**--->server side<----**

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print("--------------->SERVER<-----------------")
ip = "127.0.0.1"
port = 8080

s.bind((ip,port))
s.listen(2)
conn,addr = s.accept()
print("CONNECTED WITH THE CLIENT\n")


while True:
    #for sending message
    temp_msg = input("SERVER - ")
    message = int(temp_msg.encode())
    conn.send(message)
    
    
    #for receiving message
    rec_msg = conn.recv(1024)

    print("CLIENT - ",rec_msg, "     type = ", type(rec_msg))
```

**---> client side <----**

```
import socket
print("--------->CLIENT<----------------")
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

ip = "127.0.0.1"
port = 8080

s.connect((ip,port))
print("CLIENT1 IS CONNECTED TO THE SERVER")

while True:
    #for receiving message
    rec_msg = s.recv(1024)
    rec_msg = rec_msg
    print("SERVER - ", rec_msg,"    type = ", type(rec_msg))

    #for sending message
    temp_msg = input("CLIENT - ")
    message = int(temp_msg)
    s.send(message)
```

**----> output of client side code after sending the initial message through server.py<------**

```
--------->CLIENT<----------------
CLIENT1 IS CONNECTED TO THE SERVER
SERVER -  b''     type =  <class 'bytes'>
CLIENT -
```

Comment: I have no idea what "gets automatically destroyed" means but python sockets are a low-level protocol that send and receive only bytes. If you want to send something like an integer you have to break the integer down in individual bytes and send them that way. On the receiving end you have receive the bytes and turn them back into an integer.

Comment: The `int` type has `to_bytes` and `from_bytes` methods to help you, and you can also look into the [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) module for simplifying the task for simple types, or the [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) module for more complicated types.

Comment: You can send the integer as a string as well.  There are plenty of examples already on stack overflow.  Here's [one example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59692611/235698) that sends a file size as part of the protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a very simple method to send integer by converting them to string before sending, and then change back to to the integer format after receiving them through a socket.

**You can do this by following the below method.**

```
#server side:
num=123
# convert num to str, then encode to utf8 byte
tcpsocket.send(str(num).encode('utf8'))

#client side
data = tcpsocket.recv(1024)
# decode to unicode string 
strings = data.decode('utf8')
#get the num
num = int(strings)
```