# Bytes get concatenated while trying to send data over sockets

Tags: python, sockets

I was trying to send some data over sockets, but I noticed that the bytes I send sometimes just get concatenated together.

Sorry if the wording is not great, but here’s some example code to reproduce this problem:

```
# SERVER CODE

import socket, pickle
from _thread import start_new_thread

IP = "0.0.0.0"  # Address to bind to
PORT = 5555  # Arbitrary non-privileged port
DEFAULT_BYTES = 2048
total_connections_so_far = 0


def send(data, conn, pickle_data=True):
    try:
        if pickle_data:
            data = pickle.dumps(data)
        conn.sendall(data)
    except Exception as e:
        print("ERROR TRYING TO SEND DATA: ", e)


def threaded_client(conn, addr, user_id):

    send(b"Hello there!", conn, False)
    send(b"2nd message", conn, False)
    send(b"Last message", conn, False)

    conn.close()


with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    # bind the socket to the host address and port
    s.bind((IP, PORT))
    print("Server started at: ", s.getsockname())

    # listen for connections
    s.listen()
    print("Server has started. waiting for connections...")

    while True:

        conn, addr = s.accept()
        print("[CONNECTED]: ", addr)
        total_connections_so_far += 1  # increment the totoal connections

        # start a thread for the new client
        start_new_thread(threaded_client, (conn, addr, total_connections_so_far))
```

☝ `server.py`

```
# CLIENT CODE

import socket, pickle


class Network:
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server = ""
        self.port = 5555
        self.addr = (
            self.server,
            self.port,
        )

    # function to connect to the server
    def connect(self):
        try:
            self.client.connect(self.addr)
            print("Connected!")

        except Exception as e:
            print("error while trying to connect:", e)
            return False

    # send some data to the server
    def send(self, data, pickle_data=True):
        try:
            if pickle_data:
                data = pickle.dumps(data)

            self.client.sendall(data)

        except Exception as e:
            print("error while trying to send data:", e)
            return False

    # recieve some data from the server
    def recv(self, buffer_size=2048):
        try:
            data = self.client.recv(buffer_size)
            return data
        except Exception as e:
            print("error while recieving:", e)


client = Network()
client.connect()
data = client.recv()
print(data)
```

☝ `client.py`

---

Try running the client code a few times and you’ll notice that sometimes, the data received is a concatenation of all 3 messages sent from the server.

So to get around this problem, I have been using `time.sleep(1)` after every time I send something, but this is obviously not a great idea.

I understand that this happens cuz ( correct me if I’m wrong ) I’m only sending tiny bits of data from the server, and expecting to receive 2048 bits on the client side, so the client waits for a while to try and receive the full amount of data.

But this is a pretty common problem and there must be a neat solution to it *right*?

I know I’m a total noob, but please help me!

Comment: TCP is a stream protocol, there are no message boundaries.

Comment: So, is there no legitimate method to *add* message boundaries?

Comment: Sure add them any way you want. Put nulls or new lines between messages, or send a fixed length message, or send a size and then the message.  The only guarantee you get from TCP is the bytes arrive in the same order sent. You define what a complete message looks like and you are responsible for receiving until you have a complete message

Comment: Oh alright! I guess I was just hoping that python would do all hard work for me…
Thanks for you comment tho, I’ll try sending the size first and then receiving those many bytes on the client side.

Comment: hey @MarkTolonen, this might be a dumb question, but I just realised if I’m gonna send the length of the message first, and then the message itself… wont the “length of the message” and the “message” get concatenated?

Comment: They will, but you can read smaller amounts. So if the length is always 4 bytes, call `self.client.recv(4)` to get that.

Comment: Even recv(4) can return < 4 bytes. Buffer the reads until you have at least 4 bytes or use `socket.makefile` to wrap the socket in a file-like object that *will* read exactly 4 bytes unless the socket is closed.

Comment: Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59692611/235698).