# Socket error: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte"

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, utf-8

I am trying to implement a way to send and receive files using the socket library, but when I run the code, I keep getting the error "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte".

Sender code:

```py
import os, socket

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(("localhost", 9999))

with open("image.jpg", "rb") as file:
    file_size = os.path.getsize("send_file.txt")

    client.send("image.jpg".encode())
    client.send(str(file_size).encode())

    data = file.read()
    client.sendall(data)
    client.send(b"<DATA_END>")

    client.close()
```

Receiver code:

```py
import socket, tqdm

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(("localhost", 9999))
server.listen()

client, addr = server.accept()

file_name = client.recv(1024).decode()
print(file_name)
file_size = client.recv(1024).decode() 
print(file_size)

with open(file_name, "wb") as file:
    file_bytes = b""

    done = False

    progress = tqdm.tqdm(unit="B", unit_scale=True, unit_divisor=1000, total=int(file_size))

    while not done:
        data = client.recv(1024)
        if file_bytes[-10:] == b"<DATA_END>":
            done = True
        else:
            file_bytes += data
        progress.update(1024)

    file.write(file_bytes)

    client.close()
    server.close()
```

Comment: When writing network code you should always specify the encoding. When you just `"image.jpg".encode()`, for instance, that could be utf-8 one machine, utf-16 on another and latin1 on yet another. The `FF` suggests that you are reading a utf-16 BOM, but just a guess there. Put `"utf-8"` as the encoding for all encode and decode operations then retest.

Comment: FYI, the default for `.encode()` is `utf-8` since Python 3.2, so not as variable as, say, `open`.

Comment: Another reference for sending files: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59692611/235698

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assume that sockets honor send boundaries on receive. But that is not how a stream oriented protocol like TCP works. `send` may buffer before sending or split a send across multiple low level data link packets. `recv` just takes the data currently available. notably, you wouldnt' know if you ar are a word boundary for string decode. You need some other mechanism to decide when useful chunks of data have arrived.

A protocol that would work well in your case is to pass a header where each field is separated by newlines. Neither filename or size have a newline, so that's an easy demarcation. The receiver would read up to newline boundaries until it has filename and size, then could read exactly size bytes for the payload.

```
client.py

import os, socket

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(("localhost", 9999))

filename = "image.jpg"

with open(filename, "rb") as file:
    file_size = os.path.getsize(filename)
    # protocol <filename>\n<size>\n<data>
    client.sendall(filename.encode("utf-8"))
    client.sendall(b"\n")
    client.sendall(str(file_size).encode("utf-8"))
    client.sendall(b"\n")
    data = file.read()
    client.sendall(data)
    client.close()
```

server.py

```
def recv_to_newline(s):
    buf = []
    while True:
        c = s.recv(1)
        if not len(c):
            # socket closed
            return None
        if c == b"\n":
            return b"".join(buf)
        buf.append(c)

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(("localhost", 9999))
server.listen()

client, addr = server.accept()

file_name = recv_to_newline(client).decode("utf-8")
print(file_name)
file_size = int(client.recv(1024).decode())
print(file_size)

error = False
with open(file_name, "wb") as file:
    progress = tqdm.tqdm(unit="B", unit_scale=True, unit_divisor=1000, total=int(file_size))
    while file_size:
        data = client.recv(min(1024, file_size))
        if not data:
            print("Error: Truncated recieve")
            error = True
            break
        file.write(data)    
        progress.update(len(data))
        file_size -= len(data)

if error:
    os.remove(file_name)
    
client.close()
server.close()
```