# Python Socket Download Uplaod data

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

Iam trying to make a command-line program to transfer files from one computer to another computer.

Server sends a version number as a 4-byte integer, while client sends a bool, True if the client is getting (downloading) files and False if the client is putting(uploading) files.

When getting file, the client sends a list of strings with the filenames.(Server sends True as a bool if the file exists).

When putting file, client sends a 4-byte integer for the number of files it is putting. Client sends the number of bytes of data for the file then sends the data for each file(also sends a string for the filename.

My code so far:

```
def recv_all(sock, num_bytes):
    data = bytearray()
    while len(data) < num_bytes:
        packet = sock.recv(num_bytes - len(data))
        if not packet:
            return None
        data.extend(packet)
    return data


def recv_str(sock):
    raw_msglen = recv_all(sock, 4)
    if not raw_msglen:
        return None
    msglen = struct.unpack('>I', raw_msglen)[0]
    # Read the message data
    return recv_all(sock, msglen)

def send_str(sock, string):
   string = struct.pack('>I', len(string)) + string
    sock.sendall(string)

def send_str_list(sock, strings):
  // How Do I Sends a list of strings using the socket. and prefixed with its length as a 4-byte.
  // and use my send_str() with it?

def get_files(addr, port, filenames):
    // how to get the files from the server at addr:port?


def put_files(addr, port, filenames):
    // how to put the files from the server at addr:port?

def recv_formatted_data(sock, frmt):
   // Receives struct formatted data from the socket and returns a tuple of values
```

Can any one help completing my last parts of code ?

My source code is at: [entire code](https://github.com/rebicaay/clientserver/edit/master/file_transfer.py)
with comments on top

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve the problems yourself? What concrete problems are you facing?

Comment: @Seb can you check again I have update it, and link my source code thanks

Comment: These are multiple questions that aren't a good format for SO, but see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53145147/235698) for some techniques to solve your problem.  Post a single specific question if you get stuck.

Comment: @MarkTolonen could you complete `def recv_formatted_data(sock, frmt)` I am stuck with it