# Socket python doesn't send data if program is alive

Tags: python, sockets, server, client

I'm trying to run a client/server script, where the client sends a file to the server and waits for responses until the server sends a stop message.
The problem is: once the connection is established the client starts sending data but until I press CTRL-C the server cannot recreate the file. Only after CTRL-C print "file is fully created" and the file becomes visible, instead, before it's seems to be waiting for something. idk where the problem is. Also tried changing condition on send loop using len(), but doesn't work. Anyone know how to fix it ?

client.py :

```
import socket               # Import socket module
# from threading import Thread

s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
HOST = "101.xx.x.xxx"       # public IP address
PORT = 4243                 # Reserve a port for your service.
PDF_PATH = "exam.pdf"
s.connect((HOST, PORT))

def send():
    f = open(PDF_PATH, "rb")
    while data := f.read(4096):
        s.send(data)
    f.close()
    return
    
def receive():
    while 1:
        exercise = s.recv(4096)
        if exercise == "stop!":
            s.close()
            break
        f = open(f"{exercise}.txt", "wb")
        while data := f.read(4096):
            f.write(data)
    return

def main():
    send()
    receive()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

server.py :

```
import socket
from threading import Thread

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
HOST = socket.gethostname()
IP = socket.gethostbyname(HOST)
PORT = 4243
s.bind(('', PORT))
s.listen(5)

def receive_file(conn, i):
    f = open(f"exam.pdf", "wb")
    while received := conn.recv(4096):
        f.write(received)
    print("File is fully copied\n")
    f.close()

def send_result(conn,i):
    while 1:
        nbr = str(input("which exercise? "))
        if nbr == "stop!":
            break
        f = open(f"exercise{nbr}.txt", "rb")
        conn.send(bytes(f"exercise{nbr}.txt", encoding="utf-8"))
        while data := f.read(4096):
            conn.send(data)
        f.close()

def main():
    try:
        while 1:
            i = 0
            conn, addr = s.accept()
            print("Got connection from", addr)
            # c.send(b"Thank you for connecting")
            t = Thread(target=receive_file, args=(conn, i))
            t.start()
            t.join()
            t = Thread(target=send_result, args=(conn, i))
            t.start()
            t.join()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("interrupting \n")
        conn.close()
        s.close()


if _name_ == '_main_':
    main()
```

Comment: `if exercise == "stop!":` exercise is a `bytes` object and thus can never be equal to `"stop!"` which is a string.

Comment: yes I forgot .decode() after exercise, but problem there is no there. I solved as @Mark Tolonen said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`conn.recv()` in the server won't return `''` (no more data) unless the client closes the connection or calls `shutdown(SHUT_WR)` to indicate sends are complete:

```py
def send():
    with open(PDF_PATH, "rb") as f:
        while data := f.read(4096):
            s.sendall(data)
        s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
```

An alternative is to design a protocol that sends the length of data before the data so you know when you've received the complete transmission.  This would be required if you need to send more than one thing without closing the socket or shutting down sends.  You're going to need this to make the `receive` portion of the server work if you want to send more than one exercise file.

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53145147/235698) for an example of sending multiple files over a socket.

Comment: thanks a lot mark, it works fine for only one file.