# Want to finish and print status after file transfering in this code

Tags: python, sockets, file-transfer

I'm trying to do file transferring via sockets between two machines. I don't have any problems with transferring but I want to be able to resume inputting another command in my server after the transfer process and print that download successful after finished. This is my Server code:

```
import shlex
import socket

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(("10.87.13.44", 9999))
server.listen()
print("[+] Waiting for incoming connections")
server, addr = server.accept()
print("[+] Got a connection from " + str(addr))


def system_commands_results():
    com_result = server.recv(1024).decode()
    data_size = int(com_result)
    com_result = b""
    while len(com_result) < data_size:
        data = server.recv(4096)
        if not data:
            break
        com_result += data
    print(com_result.decode())


def receive_and_write_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path, "wb") as file:
        received_file_result = server.recv(1024)
        received_size = int(received_file_result.decode())
        received_file_result = b""
        while len(received_file_result) < received_size:
            received_data = server.recv(4096)
            if not received_data:
                break
            file.write(received_data)
        return "[+] Download successful"


while True:
    try:
        while True:
            command = input(">> ")
            command = shlex.split(command)
            if command[0] == "download":
                path = command[1]
                server.send("download".encode())
                server.send(path.encode())
                status = receive_and_write_file(path)
                print(status)
                result = server.recv(1024).decode()
                print(result)
            elif command[0] == "exit":
                server.send("exit".encode())
                exit()
            elif command[0] == "cd" and len(command) > 1:
                server.send("cd ".encode())
                change_to = command[1]
                server.send(change_to.encode())
                result = server.recv(1024).decode()
                print(result)
            else:
                server.send(command[0].encode())
                system_commands_results()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"[-] Error: {e}")
```

Client code:

```
import os
import subprocess
import socket

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(("10.87.13.44", 9999))


def execute_system_command(command):
    com_result = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, text=True)
    result_size = str(len(com_result)).encode('utf-8')
    client.send(result_size)
    chunk_size = 4096
    for i in range(0, len(com_result), chunk_size):
        client.send(com_result[i:i + chunk_size].encode('utf-8'))


def read_and_send_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path, "rb") as file:
        file_content = file.read()
        file_size = str(len(file_content)).encode()
        client.send(file_size)
        chunk = 4096
        for j in range(0, len(file_content), chunk):
            client.send(file_content[j:j + chunk])
        return "Finished"


def change_working_directory(dir_path):
    os.chdir(dir_path)
    return f"[+] Changing working directory to {os.getcwd()}"


while True:
    try:
        received_command = client.recv(1024).decode()
        if received_command == "download":
            path = client.recv(1024).decode()
            result = read_and_send_file(path)
            client.send(result.encode())
        elif received_command == "exit":
            exit()
        elif received_command == "cd ":
            change_to = client.recv(1024).decode()
            result = change_working_directory(change_to)
            client.send(result.encode())
        else:
            execute_system_command(received_command)
    except Exception as e:
        client.send(str(e).encode())
```

Right now after the transfer is completed my program just waits and I can't continue to input commands

Comment: How many breaks do you have inside the `while True:` loop?

Comment: @Daviid I'm only using exit() to end program if the command is exit. Not using break inside while loop in both codes. I didn't include other methods because It was getting too long.

Comment: It's better to have a long code to read than to have the cause of the error missing.

Comment: @Daviid I edited my both codes. all functions are included now.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53145147/235698

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/a/59692611/235698

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's, unfortunately, not 100% straightforward as discussed in the other answer's comments; you can't trust `.recv()` to always return as many bytes as you desire, so you'll need some sort of framing. For instance, HTTP, being a text-based protocol, has framing based on a double `\r\n\r\n` sequence to determine that this is the end of the client's headers, and what follows is a body (whose length is specified in the `Content-length` header.

However, this isn't HTTP, so we'll come up with a small [TLV (type-length-value) scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type%E2%80%93length%E2%80%93value) (2 bytes for message type, 4 bytes of message length); you can imagine other message types than just `1` (ping from client to server) and `2` (pong from server to client), such as `3` for "file name" and `4` for "file contents", `5` for "please run this command" and `6` for "here's that command's results" or what-have-you.

This example is self-contained in that it has two threads, a client thread, and server thread, and they talk to each other over a socket.

```
import socket
import struct
import threading
import time

port = 12340


def read_n_bytes(sock, n: int) -> bytes:
    buf = b""
    while len(buf) < n:
        buf += sock.recv(n - len(buf))
    return buf


def server():
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
        sock.bind(("localhost", port))
        sock.listen(1)
        conn, addr = sock.accept()
        handle_single_connection(conn, addr)


def read_message_header(conn):
    # if we receive less than 6 bytes, struct.unpack will also raise
    buf = conn.recv(6)
    if not buf:
        raise RuntimeError("Connection closed")
    msg_type, msg_len = struct.unpack(">HI", buf)
    return msg_type, msg_len


def write_message(sock, msg_type: int, content: bytes):
    sock.sendall(struct.pack(">HI", msg_type, len(content)))
    sock.sendall(content)


def handle_single_connection(conn, addr):
    print("Server: Connected by", addr)
    while True:
        try:
            msg_type, msg_len = read_message_header(conn)
        except RuntimeError:  # connection closed
            print("Server: Connection closed")
            break

        if msg_type == 1:  # ping
            ping_content = read_n_bytes(conn, msg_len)
            print("Server: Received ping:", ping_content)
            # Respond with a pong with the ping content reversed, for funsies
            write_message(conn, 2, ping_content[::-1])
        else:
            print("Server: Unknown message type, dying")
            break


def client():
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
        sock.connect(("localhost", port))
        for x in range(1, 10):
            message = f"hello! {1 << x}".encode("utf-8")
            write_message(sock, 1, message)
            msg_type, msg_len = read_message_header(sock)
            if msg_type == 2:  # pong
                print("Client: Received pong:", read_n_bytes(sock, msg_len))
            else:
                print("Client: Unknown message type, dying")
                break
            time.sleep(0.5)
        print("Client: closing connection")


def main():
    threading.Thread(target=server).start()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    threading.Thread(target=client).start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. so if I want to download a file from another machine we first use read_message_header to learn the size of the file then read_n_bytes to ensure all bytes readed am I right? and then do I need to make any changes when writing on the server side?

Comment: You'd come up with a protocol for that. If A is the machine requesting a download and B is the one sending it, I'd have A send a message of, say, type 1 with the name of the file, and B reply with a message of type 2 with the file's contents, or type 3 if the file doesn't exist (for example). A would then, after sending message 1, know to wait for 2 or 3, and act accordingly. So yeah, you would need changes on both sides.

Answer (score -2):

On `read_and_send_file` you return 'Finished' and then do

```
result = read_and_send_file(path)
client.send(result.encode())
```

That 'result.encode()' you send to the client will end up in the downlaoded file.

This is my `to_download.txt` file:

```
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
```

This is my `to_download.txt.new` after force closing the script.

```
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29Finished
```

Now I've modified the `server.py` doe like this:

```
def receive_and_write_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path+'.new', "wb") as file:
        received_file_result = server.recv(1024)
        received_size = int(received_file_result.decode())
        print(f"{received_file_result=}")
        print(f"{received_size=}")
        received_file_result = b""
        while len(received_file_result) < received_size:
            print("len(received_file_result) < received_size is True")
            received_data = server.recv(4096)
            print(f"{received_data=}")
            if not received_data:
                print("not received_data, break")
                break
            file.write(received_data)
    return "[+] Download successful"
```

And this is my `to_download.txt` file

```
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 Over 4096 bytes
```

Here what I get on `download to_download.txt`

```
>> download to_download.txt
received_file_result=b'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'
[-] Error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4112dcucpebzedvtqkcfzxxaacrenspypfbfyaihdkpbbjsrxturxpwmajhoecjttbzbdeiwbjnjxwukjteavmtrwwqqyzkftnwtcuefxxidgvchvxoaxilnylktlhbmfpkpcblgcqmhmosnkvlnhzypaaiojczzjyutmjnwcmrvuwpuliuoudlnpjmntykyktsdsdb
```

When your `client.py` does this:

```
def read_and_send_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path, "rb") as file:
        file_content = file.read()
        file_size = str(len(file_content)).encode()
        client.send(file_size)
        chunk = 4096
        for j in range(0, len(file_content), chunk):
            client.send(file_content[j:j + chunk])
        return "Finished"
```

You send `client.send(file_size)` and then 4096 bytes of the file contents, since on the server you always receive 1024 bytes you should pad the `file_size` on the client side.

Like so:

```
file_size = str(len(file_content)).encode().rjust(1024, b'0')
```

This way, when doing `int()` the leading 0 mean nothing, I'm not sure if there's a string length limit for `int()` but you can always use `lstrip`.

Now the output is like this:

```
[+] Waiting for incoming connections
[+] Got a connection from ('127.0.0.1', 49172)
>> download to_download.txt
received_file_result=b'0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004112'
received_size=4112
len(received_file_result) < received_size is True
received_data=b'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'
len(received_file_result) < received_size is True
received_data=b' Over 4096 bytesFinished'
len(received_file_result) < received_size is True
```

And here's the second problem:
`len(received_file_result) < received_size`

You're comparing `len('0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004112')` which is always 1024 since you do `server.recv(1024)` to `received_size` which is the full size of the file.

So, except when you download an empty file (`len('0') < 0` => `1 < 0`) you end up in an infinite loop.

Here's the updated `receive_and_write_file`:

```
def receive_and_write_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path+'.new', "wb") as file:
        padded_file_size = server.recv(1024)
        print(f"{padded_file_size=}")
        file_size = int(padded_file_size.decode())
        print(f"{file_size=}")
        received_size = 0
        while True:
            received_data = server.recv(min([file_size-received_size, 4096]))
            print(f"{received_data=}")
            if not received_data:
                print("not received_data, break")
                break
            received_size += len(received_data)
            file.write(received_data)
    return "[+] Download successful"
```

We keep track of how much data we've received in `received_size` and keep receiving data until `not received_data`.

To receive data we receive a max of 4096 bytes or whatever is left of the file if it's smaller

```
received_data = server.recv(min([file_size-received_size, 4096]))
```

With these changes the output is:

```
>> download to_download.txt
padded_file_size=b'0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004112'
file_size=4112
received_data=b'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'
received_data=b' Over 4096 bytes'
received_data=b''
not received_data, break
[+] Download successful
Finished
>>
```

PS:

not received_data, break happens because `file_size-received_size` is 0 and min picks 0, I'm not sure what happens when we do `server.recv(0)` but that might be a call that we can remove if we do

```
while received_size < file_size:
```

Comment: This is not guaranteed to work right. `recv()` reads _up to_ `n` bytes; if there are less bytes available over the wire, it'll return them. TCP streams like these really require a framing scheme such as TLV.

Comment: *if there are less bytes available over the wire, it'll return them* then do you know why does it seem to hang on `received_data = server.recv(4096)`?

Comment: "If no messages are available at the socket, the receive calls wait for a message to arrive". It will wait until there is _any_ data, but you might not get 4096 bytes.

Comment: Does it really matter if there's fewer bytes received if we're keeping track with `received_size`?

Comment: When receiving the original `padded_file_size`, you might get `b'0000000'` (as an extreme example), and then you're dead in the water.